# How to draw SVG to an image?

Tags: flutter, svg, dart, flutter-test

I really need your help.

I'm pretty sure that using `CustomPaint` would be the solution here. but I can't find the source code of Flutter's `CustomPaint` video.

I'm also aware that I must use `drawPath` to achieve this. but I can't find any resources on how to convert my **SVG** to **path**.

my scenario is this:

I have an `image`, and I also have my `SVG` wrapped in `Draggable` so I can place it anywhere on the image.

I tried using `RepaintBoundaries` but it doesn't include the `SVG` even if I try to place it as a parent widget.

I'd appreciate any help.

EDIT :

I am converting specifically, A pdf file to images.

```
Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  child: Text(
                    imageList.length == 0
                        ? "$currentPage / --"
                        : "$currentPage / ${imageList.length}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  top: 10,
                  right: 10,
                ),
                FutureBuilder(
                    future: getDocument,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(
                          child: FadingText(
                            'Rendering File ...',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      return CarouselSlider.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                            viewportFraction: 1,
                            autoPlay: false,
                            aspectRatio: 0.5,
                            enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                            onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                              setState(() {
                                currentPage = index + 1;
                                print(currentPage);
                              });
                            }),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                            child: Image.memory(snapshot.data[index]),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }),
                Positioned(
                  top: position.dy,
                  left: position.dx,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Draggable(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 120,
                          height: 70,
                          child: Center(
                            child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/signature.svg"),
                          ),
                        ),
                        childWhenDragging: Container(
                          width: 120,
                          height: 70,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Opacity(
                              opacity: 0.2,
                              child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/signature.svg"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        feedback: Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/signature.svg"),
                          ),
                          width: 120,
                          height: 70,
                        ),
                        onDraggableCanceled:
                            (Velocity velocity, Offset offset) {
                          setState(() => position = offset);
                          print(
                              "X Position : ${position.dx} | Y Position : ${position.dy}");
                          //_capturePng();
                          showDialog(
                            barrierDismissible: true,
                            context: context,
                            builder: (_) => ViewDocumentDialog(
                              x: double.parse((position.dx).toStringAsFixed(2)),
                              y: double.parse((position.dy).toStringAsFixed(2)),
                              images: encodeImageList,
                              page: currentPage,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )),
```

Comment: can you please add some code.

Comment: edited my post. thanks!

Comment: Please check out this repo that I worked on for svg using the path in custom painter and let me know if you need any help: https://github.com/sagaracharya24/custom_slider